# Excel split word into characters and rejoin it using a different delimiter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What excel formula will allow following transformation:

mRNA -> m_R_N_A

SeHCAT -> S_e_H_C_A_T

I found there is no split function although there is a concatenate function.

Comment: How long do the characters go? I could achieve it with `Replace` or `SUBSTITUTE` but it's not worth the bother of a single formula if there are huge text strings.

Comment: If one has Excel O365, this could be done through `=TEXTJOIN("_",,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1))`. It's also possible with Excel 2019 with a small adaptation of `SEQUENCE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

Assume SeHCAT is in cell A1, then do something like this `=MID($A1, COLUMNS($A$1:A$1), 1)` and it will give you "S" then drag the fill handle to the right and all the other letters will come.

**UPDATE**

There are two possible ways to concatenate.

***First:***

```
=CONCATENATE(cellrange&"_") --Don't press enter yet
```

Then select the `cellrange&"_"` and press F9 and then remove curly bracket `{`,`}` and last `_` and then press enter.
Now, this won't help if the text changes in source column and then you have to use second method.

***Second:***

Using VB script. [Check this link](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/05/28/how-to-add-a-range-of-cells-in-excel-concat/) to know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link: [your answer is in sheet "split"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c7qyNLoC3zxgTqCfmlB6HoRwBwHmjB6Q057BLNYj6Z0/edit?usp=sharing)

First: `=concatenate(MID($A2, COLUMNS($A$2:A$2), 1)," ")` for each column

Second: concatenate those back again, it should be separated by space now for each letter

Third: Ctrl+F then find-replace. Find space " ". replace with "-" or "_"

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the strings are all in column A:

As you will only want to split where there are 2 or more characters, just to start you off. In **Column C** is the formula (this is only in column C):

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>1,CONCATENATE(LEFT($A1,1),"_",MID($A1,2,1),"_"),"")
```

In **Column D** and dragged across is the formula:

```
=IF(LEN($A1)>COLUMN(C:C),CONCATENATE(C1,MID($A1,COLUMN(C:C),1),"_"),IF(LEN($A1)=COLUMN(C:C),CONCATENATE(C1,RIGHT($A1,1)),""))
```

That will build the string for you but the results will be all over the place so in **Column B** I have the formula:

```
=INDEX(1:1,1,LEN(A1)+1)
```

To gather all the results in to one column for you. Feel free to ask how any of this works, I hope this helps.

[image: Example]